# Google Translate link fails

Tags: bug, status-norepro

In [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16055/where-can-i-find-the-official-shenzen-special-economic-zone-tourism-visa-details/16064#16064) I tried to include a link to a website only available in Chinese by linking to the google translate page. While the link in the editor when writing the question looks fine, the final result after submitting looks like this:

> http://crj.gd110.gov.cn/dblj/201102/t20110216_14215.htm">

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Yes, I've seen this happen. Basically, the parser chokes because there's two http:// in Google Translate links. You could raise this on [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) or get around it by using a URL shortener to get a shortlink.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of an A, copying a Comment:

> Yes, I've seen this happen. Basically, the parser chokes because there's two http:// in Google Translate links. You could raise this on MSO or get around it by using a URL shortener to get a shortlink. – Ankur Banerjee♦ Apr 2 '13 at 1:57